# HTML jquery-plugin-circliful attributes change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, attributes

I want to change "jquery-plugin-circliful" attributes in the HTML "div" tag.

The "jquery-plugin-circliful" Library URL :  https://github.com/pguso/jquery-plugin-circliful

My HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>SVG Circliful</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.circliful.css">
</head>
<body>
<section class="container">
<h3>Circliful</h3>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <div id="test-circle" data-percent="11"></div>  **<!-- HERE  -->** 
    </div>
</div>
</section>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.circliful.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() { // 6,32 5,38 2,34
    $("#test-circle").circliful({
        animation: 1,
        animationStep: 5,
        foregroundBorderWidth: 15,
        backgroundBorderWidth: 15,
        percent: 38,
        textSize: 28,
        textStyle: 'font-size: 12px;',
        textColor: '#666',
        multiPercentage: 1,
        percentages: [10, 20, 30]
    });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Result:

[image]

I don't know why the percent value isn't changed. I tried attribute's name as "data-percent" or "percent". But anything isn't changed. What is the problem?

Comment: what do you expect the percent value to be?

Comment: in the div tag, I set the percent value as 11. I expect the 11 percent ..

Comment: But when you are instantiating the circliful you have set it to 38.

Comment: Oh.. I see. thanks. I fix the circliful attribute as removing. but just print 75% that is default value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Posted answer on behalf of OP)*.

URL: jsfiddle.net/me2loveit2/H9gak/

I applied the normal js file(jquery-plugin-circliful) in the library. but when I using div tag to change circle, some js code must be added. The url is solution. In the url, the js script (fixed) offer html div attribute change function.